# Automatic reboot timeout value

Tags: windows, windows-10, reboot, task-scheduler

Using these commands to set an automatic reboot using Task Scheduler

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\shutdown.exe -r -f -t 10
```

from here
https://www.ryadel.com/en/windows-auto-reboot-shutdown-scheduled-task-scheduler-cron/

Since this is for an installation I want to ensure it is correct. 
Can I change the timeout value (`-t`) to zero, or is it recommended to always have some positive value? I believe the default is 20 if left undefined.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I change the timeout value `-t` to zero?

Yes.

> I believe the default is 20 if left undefined.

The default is `30`.

> `/t xxx` Time until system shutdown in seconds.
>
> - The valid range for `xxx` is `0`-`315360000` seconds (10 years) [default=`30`]
> - The `/f parameter is implied when a value greater than`0`is specified for`/t`

Source [Shutdown - Shutdown the computer - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)

Note:

As pointed out by [LPChip](https://superuser.com/users/311586/lpchip) Windows Server 2008 and prior have a maximum of `21600` seconds (6 hours ).

Comment: Additional note, Windows Server 2008 and prior have a maximum of 6 hours.